# python2.7: to get stock data from yahoo finance with pandas_datareader errors

Tags: python-2.7, yahoo-finance, stock

I want to get the apple company stock data from yahoo finance with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from pandas_datareader import data



start = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

apple = data.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start)
apple.head()
```

But there is error, I know I can get from the stock data from google source, but there is no adjust_close data from google. Is the yahoo company situation influence this. Do you have another method to solve this. Thanks

```
 RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=0&ignore=.csv&s=AAPL&b=1&e=13&d=5&g=d&f=2017&c=2016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo has changed it API calls and pandas_datareader does not work anymore

You will need to download the fix-yahoo-finance package (temporarily fix) to get this to work again. You should be able to pip install this package,

```
pip install fix-yahoo-finance
```

Comment: thanks @nitin. do you have code how to use it, for example, get the stock data: begin, high, low,close, volume, adjusted_close

Comment: the code remains the same... just import fix-yahoo-finance package